# Loop Exception in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I have this code to test the performance between linked list and array list :

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 1E5; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 1E5; i++) {
    list.remove(i);
}

long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println(type + ":" + (end - start));
```

But then I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
>   50000,Size:50000.

I'm so confused. So I open my Visual Studio and tried to do the same thing with c#:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1E5; i++)
{
    numbers.Add(i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 1E5; i++)
{
    numbers.Remove(i);
}

Console.WriteLine("It's done");
```

It runs just fine. So did I do something wrong with the java code or it was something special to learn here! Sorry if I write bad English :(

Comment: Can you add the definition of `list` to the first code section?

Comment: The second code is not Java. What is it? C#?

Comment: @tobias_k yes it is

Comment: In Java there are two versions of `List#remove`: `remove(int index)` and `remove(Object o)`. Read more at documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: Regarding performance: are you sure that adding objects sequentially at the end and removing objects sequentially from the beginning is the most relevant use case for your application? Relative performance of the two list implementations depends heavily on the usage pattern.

Answer (score 5):

The `remove(int)` removes the item at the given index,
and you want to call `remove(Object)` which the .NET does.

```
list.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
list.remove(Integer.valueOf(i));
```

---

***Old answer***

While removing, the size changes, at the end there is just one element at i=0,
but you are removing 100000-1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1E5; i++) {
    list.remove(i);
}
```

Either do

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1E5; i++) {
    list.remove(0);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 1E5; i++) {
    list.remove(list.size() - 1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
    list.remove(i % list.size());
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why does the visual studio example work for him then?

Comment: @dimwittedanimal Just a guess, but I'd think that in that other language, `remove` has a different semantic, e.g. removing the number `50000` instead of the element at index `50000`. (In Java, with a `List<Integer>`, it's somewhat ambiguous)

Comment: If tobias_k is correct, than he would get same behaviour if he used `list.remove(Integer.valueOf(i))`

Comment: @dimwittedanimal Remove removes the element

Answer (score 1):

In Java, there are two version of `List.remove`: `remove(T)`, which removes the given object, no matter at what index it appears, and `remove(int)` which removed whatever object is at that index. If you have a `List<Integer>`, the two methods are somewhat ambiguous, but if you just pass an `int`, it will use `remove(int)`, which fails, as that index does not exist anymore after removing half the list.

```
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        list.add(i);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        list.remove(i);  // ERROR!
        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

If you want to remove the *value* `i`, not the element at *index* `i`, cast to `Integer`

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        list.remove((Integer) i); // works fine
        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in the remove loop you can use `list.removeLast()` or `list.remove(0)`  or `list.removeFirst()`.  when i increases the list size decreases as you remove elements from it. so your code will run until the half of the list only then the ith element will not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are looping in fixed array length while you are deleting elements in same times

Consider using `while` loop when removing instead of `for`, like this:

```
List<Integer> numbersArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> numbersLinkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

int E5 = 500000;

// For Array List test
double start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < E5; i++) {
    numbersArrayList.add(i);
}
while (!numbersLinkedList.isEmpty()) {
    numbersArrayList.remove(0);
}
double end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Array List: " + (end - start));


// For Linked List test
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < E5; i++) {
    numbersLinkedList.add(i);
}
while (!numbersLinkedList.isEmpty()) {
    numbersLinkedList.remove(0);
}
end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("linked List: " + (end - start));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to remove the elements by iterating the list then you can do it as follows.

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}

for (int i = 1000 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    list.remove(i);
}
```

What I did here is I am iterating in the reverse order. So it always delete the last element and will never throw `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`

this applies to both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`